# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric -error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to concat the following columns

```
c.coursec + ' ' +  ms.sectionn,
```

ms.secitonn is a (decimal 3,0)

Thus I am getting an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

```
c.coursec = 187C
ms.sectionn = 2
needed results is 187c-2
```

I assume I must do some kind of cast or convert?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution here?  Please consider marking answers or leaving comments if there was a different solution you've found.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, a [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) will allow your string to concatenate.

```
c.coursec + ' ' +  Convert(varchar(50), ms.sectionn),
```

[Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) is valid as well:

```
c.coursec + ' ' +  CAST( ms.sectionn AS varchar(50)),
```

Depending on the type of `c.coursec` you'll want to adjust your convert parameter.  For example if `c.coursec` is `nvarchar` then modifying the cast would be appropriate.